# Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.2.3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I have an error when shows on the command `ionic cordova platform add android`.

The error is

```
C:\Users\user3\Desktop\myApp>ionic cordova build android
> cordova platform add --save android
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add --save android (exit code 1):
    Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^6.2.3
    Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.2.3
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

My cordova version is `6.2.3`
Node js version is `6.11.1`

My android sdk in  `C:\Users\user3\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

I am also using android studio my sdk **api level is 25.**

I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

this configuaration may help you

```
cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.7.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

to bring this, use following commands

```
npm install -g ionic@2.2.0
npm install -g cordova@7.0.1
```

and make sure your node.js version is v7.7.0, you can download this version

Comment: I am using new version. when iam using 'ionic build android' it shows "The build command has been renamed. "

Comment: when using rm android it shows " Running command - failed!" "Removing platform android from config.xml file..." "Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT"

Comment: reinstall the cordova and try again, npm uninstall cordova -g   and  npm install cordova -g

Comment: I am using windows10

Comment: I am also using windows 10.                                                           
This is my working configuaration setup, i hope it will help you to understand      
cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.7.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: Then can u tell me what is the problem? what is ur npm version?

Comment: npm version 5.3.0

Comment: my npm version is 4.1.2. Is it problem in npm version.

Comment: what is your ionic version?

Comment: ionic version is 3.5.0

Comment: I have arrange the same configuration that u shown in above but it's shows the same error " Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2 "

Comment: send your configuration, ionic info

Comment: Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0

Comment: what about your node version?

Comment: Node Version: v7.7.0. All are same you are given

Comment: I am using android studio. my sdk api level is 25.

Comment: cordova platform add android@6.2.2

Comment: Now installed cordova 5.0.0 ionic 2.2.3. It's workin as well. Is there any problem for using this version?

Comment: can you update your question with new errors and configuration detail?

Comment: yes. some cordova version supports only few plugins

Comment: Sorry now i am using cordova 5.0.0. The error is same given above.